# Primefaces p:commandLink is not forwarding to face outcome page

Tags: primefaces

When I use p:commandLink the outcome page doesn't get forwarded, but h:commandLink works fine.

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable"  var="row" value="#{userFinder.list}">
    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.user_name}">
        <p:commandLink id="selectUserLink" **actionListener**="#{userSelector.edit}" value="#{row.userName}" ajax="false"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**VS**

```
<p:dataTable id="resultTable"  var="row" value="#{userFinder.list}">
    <p:column headerText="#{i18n.user_name}">
        <h:commandLink id="selectUserLink" action="#{userSelector.edit}" value="#{row.userName}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

UserSelectorImpl.java

```
@ConversationScoped
@Named("userSelector")
public class UserSelectorImpl extends AbstractEntitySelector<User> implements
     IUserSelector
{
    ...
    @Override
    public Class<? extends ViewConfig> edit()
    {
        conversation.begin();
        .. do some stuff 
        return Pages.AdminPages.UserMaintenance.EditUser.class;
    }
    ...
```

}

Pages.java

```
@Page(navigation = REDIRECT)
public interface Pages extends ViewConfig
{
   ...
   @Secured(AdminAccessDecisionVoter.class)
   public interface AdminPages extends Pages
   {
      public @Page class AdminPage implements AdminPages {}

      interface UserMaintenance extends AdminPages
      {
          public @Page class EditUser implements UserMaintenance {}
          ...
      }
   }
}
```

And I doubled check, I have /webapp/pages/adminPages/userMaintenance/editUser.xhtml

Thanks in advance,
D.

Comment: "actionListsner" a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo here, it was actionListener, but still not working :(.. (fixed above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionListener method does not forward/redirect to outcome. You should use action=""

```
<p:commandLink id="selectUserLink" action="#{userSelector.edit}" value="#{row.userName}" ajax="false"/>
```